# Proc Report and special character

Tags: sas

I would like to use proc report in SAS .

My code is :

```
define email/display style(column)={cell width=500}
```

I would like display email address. In output I haven't got @ sign. 
Please help me.

Comment: In table i have got for example : lukas@gmail.com and the output is lukasgmail.com

Comment: What did you tell PROC REPORT to use as the SPLIT character?

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have set as the SPLIT= character on the PROC statement.
Example:

```
data test;
 email='user@host';
run;
proc report data=test split='@';
 title1 "Split='@'";
 define email / flow ;
run;
proc report data=test ;
 title1 "No SPLIT= option";
 define email / flow ;
run;
```

Listing output:

```
Split='@'

  email
  user
  host


No SPLIT= option

  email
  user@host
```